# Converting Numeric Attributes To Nominal using Java Weka API?

Tags: java, weka

I'm trying to use Random Forest and Naive Bayes classifications to predict .Both gives me the error that says "RandomTree: Nominal class, please."

So, i'm trying to convert numeric attributes to nominal (I have 5400 attributes in total.)But i can't do the following:

```
  test = new Instances (br); 
  test.setClassIndex(test.numAttributes()-1); 
  NumericToNominal convert = new NumericToNominal();
  String[] options = new String[2];
```

It gives me the problem that NumericTo Nominal type does not exist.I've already imported

```
import weka.filters.Filter;
import weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.*;
```

any help would be appreciated.thanks

Comment: Maybe the version you use doesn't have a `NumericToNominal`, how about using your IDE to search the class?

Comment: Which Weka version are you using?